# AngularJS - передача объекта в контроллер извне

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

В файле шаблона создается AngularJS приложение. В этом файле шаблона есть доступ к php переменной `$json`, в этой переменной, как вы поняли, json-объект, созданный на бекенде. Нужно передать этот объект в `$scope` AngularJS приложения. Есть ли правильный способ? По сути, нужно наверное что-то типа инициализирующей функции приложения Angular, которая скушала бы этот объект. Конечно, можно просто подтянуть эти данные в самом Angular, с помощью AJAX, но не хочется лишних запросов делать.

Comment: Если вам надо "вписать" значение на момент генерации страницы `app.value('myJson', <? php pleace put this here ?>)`. Если нет, то только через запрос к серверу. Angular поддерживает упрощенный код  запросов. А вы не используете никакой фреймворк php + Angular?

Comment: Ок, спасибо, видимо всё же придется делать запрос. Использую yii2 + angular

Comment: сделайте этот JSON глобальной переменной и берите откуда угодно.

Comment: @cheeseq, когда получится, отпишитесь в теме, чтобы не оставалась без ответа.

Comment: Посмотрите пример в https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: yii2 очень популярный, там 100% должна быть фишка для прелоада значений.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую поискать. И с тем и с другим работаю практически впервые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы про это:

```
var jPHP = '<?=$json?>';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window){
    $scopr.jPHP = $window.jPHP
});
```

**UPD1**
Приведу еще ссылочку пожалуй: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант, но не хочется оставлять возможностей для всяких нехороших товарищей просто менять объект через консоль и сводить приложение с ума :)

Comment: Клиентский JS исполняется на стороне, внезапно, `клиента`. Поэтому в любом случае ввсегда есть возможность сводить приложения с ума.

Comment: Все верно  сказал @maxwell. Для это (для самых умных) используйте backend.

Comment: Я не так выразился, наверное, но не важно. В любом случае ваш вариант рабочий для изначальной задачи.